# iCloud Testing of application in iOS simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, icloud

I am new to the iOS application development and i came across a situation where i need to perform iCloud testing using XCode to check if it is working properly. Can anyone please suggest the steps that needs to be followed in order to perform iCloud testing of iOS application?

Answer (score 2):

You can login to iCloud in the simulator. Open Settings, then login to iCloud just like you would on a device.

I *highly* recommend using a test account, not your actual account. I also recommend that you have that test account login on a real physical device at least once somewhere to enable additional storage and features on the account.

From that point iCloud should report as available in the simulator.

To trigger a sync with the server, use the "Trigger iCloud Sync" menu item. Simulators don't currently have server-side push notification support so the simulator device is not notified immediately about CloudKit subscriptions.

If you run into any problems please file a feedback report after reproducing the problem, then running `xcrun simctl diagnose` to gather logs.

Comment: Just be aware that triggering a sync doesn't produce an instant sync. I've not figured out how much of a delay there is or what is required to happen after selecting that, but I have noticed there is a significant delay. But it does eventually sync.